# Efficient contours of a non-binary image

Tags: python-3.x, mask, contour, opencv, python

I have this image:
[image]

I want to get the contours of every unique (none-zero) value, so basically this output:

```
[array([[1, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 1]], dtype=int32),
 array([[4, 2],
        [4, 3],
        [5, 3],
        [5, 2]], dtype=int32),
 array([[2, 4],
        [3, 4]], dtype=int32)]
```

I can achieve this by converting the image into binary mask and then using `cv2`'s `findContours` function, which get the output which I want.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,2,2,0],
    [0,0,0,0,2,2,0],
    [0,0,3,3,0,0,0]
])

contour_list = []

for level in [l for l in np.unique(img) if l != 0]:
    mask = (img == level).astype(np.uint8)
    contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]
    contours[0] = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0], 0.5, True)
    contours_xy = contours[0][:, 0]
    contour_list.append(contours_xy)


contour_list
```

However, this approach is slow for large images with many unique levels. Is there a way to improve the speed of this function (without multiprocessing)? I feel like I'm overlooking some functionality.

Comment: From my point of view, your approach is the way to go - especially, since you have to deal with contours touching each other. If you don't need the "level information" in the later contour_list, maybe you can preprocess your input image, e.g. setting all contours without touching another one to the same level. But, I'm not sure, whether this saves so much processing time compared to your approach as is.

Comment: Resize your original image , do the process,  than scale the resulted contours to fit your original image.

Answer (score 0):

Resize your original image , do the process, than scale the resulted contours to fit your original image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('images/multi-level-color.png',0)
img_r = cv2.resize(img,(int(img.shape[1]*0.1),int(img.shape[0]*0.1)))

cv2.imshow('img_r',img_r)
cv2.waitKey(0)

contour_list = []
contour_list_r = []

for level in [l for l in np.unique(img) if l != 0]:
    #mask = (img == level).astype(np.uint8)

    contours = cv2.findContours(img_r, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]
    contours[0] = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0], 0.5, True)
    contours_xy = contours[0][:, 0]
    contours_xy_r = contours[0][:, 0]*10

    contour_list.append(contours_xy)
    contour_list_r.append(contours_xy_r)


print("resized 0.1",contour_list[0])

print("resized 10",contour_list_r[0])
```

original image:
[image]

resized image to process:
[image]

**Output:**

**resized 0.1**

```
[[11 10]
 [11 20]
 [20 20]
 [21 21]
 [21 31]
 [42 31]
 [43 32]
 [43 41]
 [42 42]
 [21 42]
 [21 52]
 [42 52]
 [42 42]
 [43 41]
 [63 41]
 [63 21]
 [43 21]
 [42 20]
 [42 10]]
```

**resized 10**

```
[[110 100]
 [110 200]
 [200 200]
 [210 210]
 [210 310]
 [420 310]
 [430 320]
 [430 410]
 [420 420]
 [210 420]
 [210 520]
 [420 520]
 [420 420]
 [430 410]
 [630 410]
 [630 210]
 [430 210]
 [420 200]
 [420 100]]
```